# Easy way to replace last character in file?

Tags: python, file-io

I simply want to replace the last character in my file. The reason is because when I write to my file, at the last point in which I write to the file, there is an extra `,` that is included at the end. I simply don't want to write that `,` at the end, but rather would want to replace it with a `]` if possible. Here is my attempt:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(restaurantsCsv), delimiter=';')
  with open(fileName, 'w+') as textFile:
    textFile.write('[')
    for row in reader:
      newRow = {}
      for key, value in row.items():
        if key == 'stars_count' or key == 'reviews_count':
          newRow[key] = float(value)
        else:
          newRow[key] = value
      textFile.write(json.dumps(newRow) + ',')
    textFile.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    textFile.truncate()
    textFile.write(']')
```

It all works properly until I get to `textFile.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)` where I want to seek the end of the file and I want to remove that last `,` in the file, but I get an error saying `io.UnsupportedOperation: can't do nonzero end-relative seeks`. Therefore, I made it so that my file opens with `wb+` parameters, but if I do that, then I can only write bytes to my file, and not strings. Is there any way I can simply replace the last character in my file with a `]` instead of a `,`? I know I can simply open the file to read, truncate the file, then open the file again to write the last `]` but that seems inefficient (as shown here):

```
   with open(filename, 'rb+') as filehandle:
     filehandle.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
     filehandle.truncate()

   with open(filename, 'a') as filehandle:
    filehandle.write(']')
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where is that `,` coming from? Where's the code for generating the file? Instead of going back to overwrite the last character of the file, I'd recommend preventing the problem from happening in the first place. Fix causes, not symptoms.

Comment: @Chris it actually comes from here: `textFile.write(json.dumps(newRow) + ',')` where the when I write to the file, the last row I write to the file includes a `,`. The problem is, the `,` should be there in every case except for at the last row.

Comment: Should the whole file contain valid JSON? Don't build that up manually. You're already using `json.dumps()` for individual rows; why aren't you using it for the full output?

Comment: Yes. You should handle the error at source. Instead of making it and fixing later. :)

Comment: @Chris yes, the whole file  should contain valid JSON. I understand I am using `json.dumps()` for individual rows, but that is because I need to make sure that when reading my file, the `csvReader` interprets floats correctly. What do you mean why aren't I using it for the full output?

Comment: @user1871869, if you have a list of `newRow`s and pass the whole list into `json.dumps()` you'll get a valid JSON string for the whole thing. The library will take care of putting `,`s, `[`s and `]`s (and other structural characters) where they need to go. And if _that_ structure goes inside something else, you can pass _it_ into `json.dumps()`. Basically, pass the whole top-level data structure that should be JSON into `json.dumps()`.

Comment: @user1871869 Hey I missed it that you want to replace last character of last line. Modified the sed command now. It will replace last character of last line with ]. But try to handle the error at source.

Comment: @user1871869 You can also use pandas to convert csv to json very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Chris, accumulate all the new rows in a list then write all those row once.  Then you won't have that pesky hanging comma.

```
......
    rows = []
    for row in reader:
        newRow = {}
        for key, value in row.items():
            if key == 'stars_count' or key == 'reviews_count':
                newRow[key] = float(value)
            else:
                newRow[key] = value
        rows.append(newRow)
    textFile.write(json.dumps(rows))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can slightly modify your approach and instead of appending a comma at the end of each line, you just prepend a comma to every line but the first:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(restaurantsCsv), delimiter=';')

with open(fileName, 'w+') as text_file:
    text_file.write('[')

    for index, row in enumerate(reader):
        new_row = {}

        for key, value in row.items():
            if key in ('stars_count', 'reviews_count'):
                new_row[key] = float(value)
            else:
                new_row[key] = value

        if index != 0:
            text_file.write(',')

        text_file.write(json.dumps(new_row))

    text_file.write(']')
```

Answer (score 2):

To replace last character of the file, i.e. last character of last line.

To see if its working properly

```
sed '$ s/.$/]/' file_name
```

To replace the last character of last line i.e comma in your case  with ']' and change the file.

```
sed -i '$ s/.$/]/' file_name
```

To run from within python

```
import os
print os.system("sed -i '$ s/.$/]/' file_name")
```

Comment: I would like a way to automate it using my python script if possible. Thanks.

Comment: If it's working for you then you can use os.system() function in python to use this same command.